# How to correctly remove entries from firewalld ipset runtime?

Tags: debian, fail2ban, firewalld, ipset

Running Debian 12

I have created an IPSet in the following manner:

```
~$ firewall-cmd --permanent --new-ipset=myipset --type=hash:ip --option=timeout=0
success
~$ firewall-cmd --reload
success
~$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=drop --add-source=ipset:myipset
success
~$ firewall-cmd --zone=drop --list-sources
ipset:myipset
```

I add an IP to the list:

```
~$ firewall-cmd --ipset=myipset --add-entry=1.2.3.4
success
~$ firewall-cmd --ipset=myipset --get-entries
1.2.3.4
```

I attempt to remove:

```
~$ firewall-cmd --ipset=myipset --remove-entry=1.2.3.4
success
```

However, when I again check the entries, the ip is still present:

```
~$ firewall-cmd --ipset=myipset --get-entries
1.2.3.4
```

The behaviour works as expected in the permanent environment. Is this a bug or expected behaviour?

Is there another way to manage this? I am trying to use firewalld ipsets for fail2ban action, and the issue is apparent when attempting a 2nd ban of an IP within the same jail.

I would prefer to avoid reloading firewalld everytime an action takes place in order to reduce load.